# Print a string and call a class method (that contains 'input') in the same line

Tags: python, class, input, printing

So I want to print a string and then call a method, which is inside the class within the same line.

My code is following:

```
class A:
    
    def a(self):
        return 'bla bla\n' + A.b(self)
    
    def b(self):
        self.input = input('Type here:')
        if self.input == 'yes':
            return '\nok'
        else:
            return '\nnot ok'
    
d = A()

print(d.a())
```

*The results I get:*

```
Type here: (when I type 'Yes')

bla bla

ok
```

*What I want is this:*

```
bla bla

Type here: (when I type 'Yes')

ok
```

I want that 'bla bla' would be displayed first and then based on the input you would get either 'ok' or 'not ok'.

Can someone please help with what do I need to change?

Comment: Mixing concatenation of strings and printing directly will make this harder than it needs to be. `b` needs to be called before `a` can return, which means the `input` string will be printed first. I'd move the input-asking code out, pass the result into `b`, and have `b` make decisions based on already-received input.

Comment: it is completely business logic, not technical problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change method `a` like -

```
def a(self):
    print('bla bla\n')
    return A.b(self)
```

The print statement will execute first and then return method `b` and asks you the input

Comment: Great idea! Thanks! Don't know how I didn't come up with that (am quite new in Python).